# LAN network freezes

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, lan

I have three Ubuntu computers connected to a router. Everything's OK, both have internet conections running well and can connect via `ssh` to each other.

In one computer, I usually launch a softwared called Blast2GO, a java-based program that needs internet conection to work in order to connect to any servers. The thing is that during the day everything works great, but something happens along the night. The following day, the network is collapsed and the computer running Blast2Go frozen. Neither internet connection in the other computers nor they can connect between them. The only way back to normality is to turn the computer running Blast2GO down.

Could you give me some clues about what can I do in order to discover the origin of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Logging. Does Blast2Go have logging? Turn it on. Google & find out as much as you can about Linux logging in general and network logging in particular. Also, log resource usage, since you say that "the computer running Blast2Go frozen" - maybe out of RAM?

Comment: 1) It is not out of RAM... yesterday I connected to the computer running Blast2GO from another computer and I executed a top from the terminal. This morning I've seen the moment `Broken pipe`, and Blast2GO consumed only 10% of RAM resources. 2) Blast2GO does not need logging to work.

Comment: It could be that the Blast2GO computer is flooding the router with traffic - is there an option to limit the traffic in Blast2GO? You could also configure the router with QoS rules.

Comment: But if it is flooding, why the hell it works great along the day and flooding only occurs at night? Moreover, traffic comes from internet, and router and computer are connected with CAP6... I don't see why flooding would occur. Btw, couldn't it be a network conflict with Blast2GO and any process executed only at night?